# Using libtool without using links

Tags: vmware, symlink, autotools, libtool

My `Makfile` is using `libtool` in order to create some apache modules.

Unfortunately I need my makefile to work on a VMWare shared forlder (`hgfs`), which does not support any kind of links (symbolic or hard links).

Can I use `libtool` and have it use `cp` instead of `ln -s`, WITHOUT patching the `LN_ST` variable in the script, and thus breaking `libtool` for the rest of the system while preventing future upgrades to `libtool`?

Comment: Could you use a shell alias to make ln just do a cp instead?

Comment: Why not patch the `LN_S` variable in the script? That's what `AC_PROG_LN_S` is for...

Comment: @ptomato I don't remember the specific case, but IIRC changing the program doesn't change the fact that libtool uses it as a file. That said, I should probably set `AC_PROG_LN_S` to my own script, which would contain the logic.

Comment: If you have enough RAM in your VM, you could compile on a RAM-disk and then copy the results to the shared folder (probably tgz'ed). http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-create-linux-ram-disk-filesystem/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.sourceware.org/autobook/autobook/autobook_220.html

> **ln**
>
> Not all systems support soft links. You should use the Autoconf
>   macro `AC_PROG_LN_S' to discover what the target architecture
>   supports, and assign the result of that test to a variable. Whenever
>   you subsequently need to create a link you can use the command stored
>   in the variable to do so.
>
> ```
> LN_S=@LN_S@
> ...
> $LN_S $top_srcdir/foo $dist_dir/foo
> ```
>
> Also, you cannot rely on support for the `-f' option from all
>   implementations of ln. Use rm before calling ln instead.